# How to scatter plot where X axis is continuous and Y axis categorical with 1 and 0 with 2 different colours?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

X=[10,20,30,40,50]
y=[1,0,1,0,1]

How to get a plot with 1's in green and 0's in red?[image: resultant graph]

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about.

Comment: @Lorddirt sorry, I have updated the question now.!

Comment: Graph might seem to have  no meaning because its just a small part of the actual dataset.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of colors to be passed to `plt.scatter` using a simple list comprehension.

```
x=[10,20,30,40,50]
y=[1,0,1,0,1]

colors = ["seagreen" if i == 1 else "red" for i in y]

plt.scatter(x, y, color=colors)
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The graph can be replicated using the `y` values for the `c` argument and mapping those with a colormap of choice.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=[10,20,30,40,50]
y=[1,0,1,0,1]

plt.scatter(x, np.zeros(len(x)), c=y, cmap="RdYlGn")
plt.tick_params(axis="y", left=False, labelleft=False, )
plt.show()
```

[image]